# making two tables in the same jScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jtable, netbeans-8

I want to make many tables in the same pane and show the one I want by clicking on a button by hidding a table and showing the other , the problem is i can't put a table on top of the other in NetBeans.  How can i put all tables one above the other?

Comment: Use a `JPanel` with a `BorderLayout`, and add the two tables at `BorderLayout.EAST` and `BorderLayout.WEST`, then add the `JPanel` to the scroll pane.

Comment: i have 7 tables actually

Comment: Then use a whole load of nested JPanels.

Comment: The simple solution: use one JTable and simply swap models when need be. The JTable tutorial will show you how to do this, but all it requires is that you call `setModel(...)` on the single JTable, passing in the model desired.

Comment: Perhaps a job for `CardLayout`?

Answer (score 2):

> and show the one I want by clicking on a button by hidding a table and showing the other

Don't attempt to have two tables in the same scrollpane.

If you want to change the component in the scrollpane you would just use:

```
scrollPane.setViewportView( theOtherTable );
```

Or you can just change the model of the table:

```
table.setModel( ... );
```